# Heroku SSL host not working (Heroku | No such app)

Tags: ssl, heroku

I successfully used Letsencrypt to generate certificates and I uploaded them to Heroku using:

```
this-site ********$ heroku addons:create ssl:endpoint
Creating ssl-graceful-41756... done, ($20.00/month)
Adding ssl-graceful-41756 to this-site... done
Next add your certificate with `heroku certs:add CERT KEY`.
Use `heroku addons:docs ssl` to view documentation.

this-site ********$ sudo heroku certs:add /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.this-site.com/fullchain.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.this-site.com/privkey.pem
Resolving trust chain... done
Adding SSL Endpoint to this-site... done
this-site now served by qwasf-34234.herokussl.com
Certificate details:
Common Name(s): www.this-site.com
Expires At:     2016-09-02 19:15 UTC
Issuer:         /C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
Starts At:      2016-06-04 19:15 UTC
Subject:        /CN=www.this-site.com
SSL certificate is verified by a root authority.
```

However, when I visit qwasf-34234.herokussl.com, it is not working.  It has a page that says: Heroku | No such app ; There is no app configured at that hostname.
Perhaps the app owner has renamed it, or you mistyped the URL.

I am copy and pasting the exact new host that heroku gave me.  Going to https://qwasf-34234.herokussl.com yields the same page.

I verified the certificate with:

```
this-site ********$ heroku certs
Endpoint                    Common Name(s)         Expires               Trusted
--------------------------  ---------------------  --------------------  -------
qwasf-34234.herokussl.com  www.this-site.com  2016-09-02 19:15 UTC  True
```

More checks:

```
this-site *******$ curl -kvI https://www.this-site.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.michaelsutyak.com/
*   Trying 23.21.142.230...
* Connected to www.this-site.com (23.21.142.230) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_********************
* Server certificate: *.herokuapp.com
* Server certificate: DigiCert ******
* Server certificate: DigiCert *******
> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.this-site.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Cowboy
Server: Cowboy
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Date: Sat, 04 Jun 2016 20:57:00 GMT
Date: Sat, 04 Jun 2016 20:57:00 GMT
< Via: 1.1 vegur
Via: 1.1 vegur

< 
* Connection #0 to host www.this-site.com left intact
```

What is going on here and how can this work?  I just want https for my site.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the Heroku SSL endpoint directly. That endpoint represents the hostname where you need to point your domain to, as explained in the [DNS and domain configuration](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint#dns-and-domain-configuration) of the Heroku article.

If you want to point a subdomain (e.g. www.this-site.com), then create a DNS record CNAME in your DNS hosting provider that points the `www` record to the Heroku SSL endpoint:

```
www CNAME qwasf-34234.herokussl.com
```

If you want to point the root domain (this-site.com), then you need to use a provide that supports the CNAME-like record for the root domain, as [explained in this Heroku article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#configuring-dns-for-root-domains) as [you can't use a CNAME for the root domain](https://blog.dnsimple.com/2014/01/why-alias-record/).

Make sure your domain is not still pointing to the `herokuapp.com` hostname.

You can test my assertion by sending a `cURL` request to the SSL endpoint, but passing the `Host` header (as the browser would do).

```
$ curl -i qwasf-34234.herokussl.com -H "Host: www.this-site.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot visit the `qwasf-34234.herokussl.com` domain that Heroku gives you. Instead, you are supposed to change your DNS to point to that as a CNAME, instead of `qwasf-34234.herokuapp.com`.